# Удаление всего что входит в фигурные скобки python

Tags: python

Мне нужно удалять любое вхождение в фигурные скобки, вот что у меня получилось:

файл:

```
bfyby4hebfn{3}gfu4hr4u{g7h8idej}fuhe
e5yrc6ut7gy{erctvy}rtfgy{2}drftgyg5r
```

Программа:

```
f = open('st.txt')
for j in range(2):
    n = f.readline()
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if n[i] == '{':
            n.split('}', 1)[:1]
    print(n)
```

но выходит такая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как мне ее исправить?
заранее спасибо

Comment: предупреждение связано с тем, что выражение `n.split('}', 1)[:1]` возвращает какое-то значение, вы его никак не используете.

Comment: а как тогда удалять все значения?

Comment: пользуйтесь регулярными выражениями.

Comment: вам не надо split, вам надо  узнать индекс следующей закрывающей скобки, и в новую строку переписать без этого кусочка

Comment: строка не может быть исправлена так сказать на месте,ее нужно переписывать в другую с изменением

Comment: понятно, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txt = 'bfyby4hebfn{3}gfu4hr4u{g7h8idej}fuhee5yrc6ut7gy{erctvy}rtfgy{2}drftgyg5r'
# 1
print(''.join(x[x.find('}')+1:] for x in txt.split('{')))
# 2
print(''.join(x.split('{')[0] for x in txt.split('}')))
```

Comment: А вот и `.split()` из оригинального вопроса пригодился

Answer (score 0):

По комментариям, `.split()` действительно не совсем понятно зачем нужен. Можно через `.replace()`:

```python
f = open('st.txt')
for j in range(2):
    n = f.readline()
    while n.find('{') != -1:
        n = n.replace(n[n.find('{'):n.find('}')+1], '')
    print(n)
f.close()
```

###### Вывод:

```
bfyby4hebfngfu4hr4ufuhe
e5yrc6ut7gyrtfgydrftgyg5r
```

Пока в строке есть фигурные скобки, берём их и их содержимое, меняем строковую переменную и убираем поочерёдно.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не хотите/не можете использовать регулярки, то можно так:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        while (i := line.find('{')) != -1:
            line = line[:i] + line[line.find('}')+1:]
        print(line)
```

Comment: Так отрубит до первой скобки, т.е. получится **bfuhe** и **edrftgyg5r**

Comment: @DiMithras забыл скобочки поставить =) спасибо за замечание

Answer (score 0):

Решение в стиле `C`. Файл считывается посимвольно. `level` хранит вложенность фигурных скобок:

```
with open('st.txt') as f:
    level = 0
    while c := f.read(1):
        if c == '{':
            level += 1
        if level == 0:
            print(c, end='')
        if c == '}':
            level -= 1
```

Решение в противоположном стиле. Файл считывается целиком, текст обрабатывается регулярным выражением:

```
import re


with open('temp.txt') as f:
    print(re.sub('\\{.*?\\}', '', f.read(), flags=re.DOTALL), end='')
```